# publishing user relevant data

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have created a simple, minimalistic [diary app](http://thediary.meteor.com/).

On the client, I use

```
Meteor.subscribe('entries', Meteor.userId());
```

to subscribe to the entries created by the user (stored in a mongodb collection). I pass the users ID to the publish function (on the server):

```
Meteor.publish('entries', function(userID) { 
    return Entries.find({userId: userID});
});
```

After login, `Meteor.userId()` isn't falsy anymore, because it's a reactive data source. However, the relevant data is not being published. I fixed that by auto-running the subscribe function:

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('entries', Meteor.userId());
});
```

It works, but I feel it's a bad solution.

**So here comes the question:**
How should one publish user-relevant data in general? There must be a better way to do this, than passing the users ID to the publish-function. Also, isn't it insecure?

By the way, would love to hear some feedback on the app

Comment: In your publish function, you have access to `this.userId` to safely retrieve the ID of the calling user. - Edit: I feel like it should be the answer to your question! Want me to post it as so?

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that I had access on the current user through 'this'. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass the userId from the subscription. Inside the [publish](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-publish) function you can use `this.userId` to get the current user. You can also just return an empty array if the user is not logged in.

```
Meteor.publish("entries", function () {
  if (!this.userId) return [];
  return Entries.find({ userId: this.userId });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that! So generally, we use `this.userId`  on the server inside the publish function to get user relevant data?

Comment: Yes, you don't want to take it from subscriptions (or method calls) since the user could send any id.